# Выборка из БД Realm Android

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-database

Решил попробовать данную БД для работы, но никак не пойму, как вытаскивать оттуда данные. Занести получилось, потом использую:
`realm.where(Class.class)findAll();`
И получаю строку вида: `[Class = [{string1: X}, {string2:Y}], [Class = [{string1: X}, {string2:Y}], [Class = [{string1: X}, {string2:Y}]...`
и так до конца всей таблицы. Так вот, как вытащить значения именно string1 или string2, что бы потом занести их в массив и уже работать с ними?

Вот моя модель данных

```
public class Test extends RealmObject {

    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;

    public String getFirstName(){return firstName;}

    public void setFirstName(String x_firstName) {this.firstName= x_firstName;}

    public String getSecondName(){return secondName;}

    public void setSecondName(String x_secondName) {this.secondName= x_secondName;}
}
```

Comment: Покажите код класса, объекты которого хранятся в БД.

Comment: `findAll()` возвращает `RealmResults<E>`, в котором собственно и находятся выбранные объекты.

Answer (score 3):

Метод `findAll()` возвращает объект типа `RealmResults<E>`, В Вашем случае это `RealmResults<Test>`.

Далее, из `RealmResults<Test>` Вы можете получать объекты:

```
RealmResults<Test> tests = realm.where(Test.class).findAll();
Test test = tests.get(0);
```

И обращаться к содержимому объекта:

```
String firstName = test.getFirstName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы делаете запрос к реалму на предмет сохранённых в нём записей вам надо указывать конкретный класс записи. Т.е. в вашем случае - указать класс `Test`. В итоге вы получите объект `RealmResults<Test>`:

```
RealmResults<Test> tests = realm.where(Test.class).findAll();
```

далее вы можете работать с результатом как с реализацией `List<Test>`. Например:

```
System.out.println(tests.get(0).getFirstName());
```